# Could a ClickOnce installation be updated via Windows Update?

Tags: .net, windows, clickonce

I am wondering whether a ClickOnce application installed on a target PC could check for updates, by taking advantage from the Windows Updates engine.

Just to fix the point, let's supposing that an application A is published (via ClickOnce) on the web, such as many users can install it. Also imagine that new versions of the app A is published quite often (e.g. 2-3 times/week). Finally let's assume that some users have a good web connection, while other don't, and I really would like that every user could adjust the checking frequency as best he fits.

Since there is already a scheduling task for the Windows Updates, is it possible to include the checking for my app A in that scheduler?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to do so, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) shows there are only three available deployment options; Install via Web/Network Share, CD or starting directly from the Web/Network Share.

If you then look at the [update management documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) that is provided to you they seem to emphasise connecting to a web server to check for updates and download them if necessary, again based on the original installation method.

I'm going to assume Microsoft want to keep control of the Windows Update method, locking out other developers from tinkering with it would be a sure fire way to ensure it's stable and that users get the updates that are necessary.

Comment: Perhaps You could be right, but if you take a look at the Windows Update dialog (Windows Vista/7), there is a label "You receive updates for:". Either that is an useless indication, or probably there is some way to add other stuffs.

Comment: I believe that's there to enable Windows Update to recieve updates for other Microsoft products such as Office, not just Windows.